# Q Network Access manager in pyQt Python (Segmentation Fault Core Dumped)

Tags: python, pyqt, qwebview

i have developed an application using pyQt in python and using a web browser and a table to show the headers coming with the browser request.
here is my code:-

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl  
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView, QWebPage
from PyQt4.QtGui import QGridLayout, QLineEdit, QWidget, QHeaderView
from PyQt4.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkRequest


class RequestsTable(QTableWidget):
    header = ["url", "status", "content-type","cookies","user_agent"]

    def __init__(self):
        super(RequestsTable, self).__init__()
        self.setColumnCount(5)
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.header)
        header = self.horizontalHeader()
        header.setStretchLastSection(True)

    def update(self, data):
        last_row = self.rowCount()
        next_row = last_row + 1
        self.setRowCount(next_row)
        for col, dat in enumerate(data, 0):
            if not dat:
                 continue
            self.setItem(last_row, col, QTableWidgetItem(dat))

class Manager(QNetworkAccessManager):
    def __init__(self, table):
        QNetworkAccessManager.__init__(self)
        self.finished.connect(self._finished)
        self.table = table

    def _finished(self, reply):
        user_agent = str(reply.request().rawHeader("User-Agent"))
        headers = reply.rawHeaderPairs()
        headers = {str(k):str(v) for k,v in headers}
        content_type = headers.get("Content-Type")
        url = reply.url().toString()
        status =    reply.attribute(QNetworkRequest.HttpStatusCodeAttribute)
        status, ok = status.toInt()
        cookies = headers.get("Set-Cookie")
        self.table.update([url, str(status),             content_type,cookies,user_agent])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    grid = QGridLayout()
    browser = QWebView()
    browser.load(QUrl("http://www.indiatimes.com/"))
    def on_html_available():
        page = QWebPage()
        page.setNetworkAccessManager(manager)

        # problem is here
        browser.setPage(page)
        # if i dont use above line then it don't show any error but the headers don't get append in the table but if i use the above line it shows me the error segmentation fault

    browser.loadFinished.connect(on_html_available)
    requests_table = RequestsTable()
    manager = Manager(requests_table)
    grid.addWidget(browser, 3, 0)
    grid.addWidget(requests_table, 4, 0)
    main_frame = QWidget()
    main_frame.setLayout(grid)
    main_frame.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

but the above code is showing me the error

```
"core dumped segmentation fault"?
```

what may be the problem ? please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its showing this error because you are again setting the browser's page on html finished, which is wrong, to access network access manager you should first take the manager then set the manager with page and then set the browser page. let me know if you don't get this.